# Pricing for Azure ARM template

Tags: azure, powerbi, price

I am following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-security-private-links) tutorial to provide secure access via private endpoints to Power BI.
In [this step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-security-private-links#create-a-power-bi-resource-in-the-azure-portal) i have to create a a Power BI resource (ARM template). I have to buy this template, but i am not able to find a pricing for this one.

Basically i have a database which is connected with a private link to a virtual network. Now i want to access this database with the Power BI App.

Comment: Here is the pricing for Private Link at least: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/private-link/

Comment: yeah, i also found the pricing for private link, but its about this tutorial step: "In the dialog that appears, select the checkbox to agree to the terms and conditions, and then select Purchase."
I'll have to buy the Azure Template.

Comment: @juunas i updated my post, so you see what I have in mind. Maybe there are other possibilities

Comment: *I'll have to buy the Azure Template* No, that is not what the button implies. If you read the text carefully it sais that you will be billed for the resource that is provisioned by the ARM template.

Comment: so i'll guess in this context, its about a new (one!) private link "Microsoft.PowerBI/privateLinkServicesForPowerBI" ?

Comment: You always have to “purchase” resources in Azure even so that resource cost nothing, like resource group. It’s just the way Azure works